# SQL case/if condition Join tbl A or tbl B

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

SQL Server...

I need to Join tbl_B or tbl_C with tbl_A. Case tblA.id = 1 Join B or Case tblA.id = 2 Join C

let's say this example:

```
Table: tblFood
    Id_Food | Fk_Id_Foodtype
    1       | 1
    1       | 2

Table: tabVegetable
    Id      | Mame     |Color
    1       | eggplant |black

Table: tabFrute
    Id      | Name     |Color
    1       | apple    |red
```

On the table **tblFood** above...

if **Fk_Id_Foodtype** = 1 join **Id_Food** on **tabVegetable**

if **Fk_Id_Foodtype** = 2 join **Id_Food** on **tabFrute**

So I can return execute a select like this: **SELECT tblFood.Id_Food**, (*tabVegetable or tabFrute*).**name**, (*tabVegetable or tabFrute*).**color**

Note: I only have tblFruts and tblVegetable, so I always check these two option.

Thank you!

Comment: What is your question? You provide specs but do not point out your specific issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join to `tblFood` the other tables with `LEFT` joins and in the `ON` clauses specify the condition for `Fk_Id_Foodtype`.
In the `SELECT` list of columns use `COALESCE()` to get the values of the columns from each table:

```
SELECT f.*,
       COALESCE(v.Name, fr.Name) Name,
       COALESCE(v.Color, fr.Color) Color
FROM tblFood f
LEFT JOIN tabVegetable v ON f.Fk_Id_Foodtype = 1 AND v.Id = f.Id
LEFT JOIN tabFrute fr ON f.Fk_Id_Foodtype = 2 AND fr.Id = f.Id
```